# I am facing problem while installing laravel package maatwebiste/excel in laravel 9 with php 8.0.3

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

Problem 1
- maatwebsite/excel[3.1.36, ..., 3.1.x-dev] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.18 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.18.0, ..., 1.23.0].
- maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.1.25] require php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
- maatwebsite/excel[3.1.26, ..., 3.1.35] require illuminate/support 5.8.*|^6.0|^7.0|^8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.18.0, ..., 1.23.0] require ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
- Root composer.json requires maatwebsite/excel ^3.1 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.1.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-gd` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require maatwebsite/excel:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require maatwebsite/excel:^2.1" if you know which you need.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7FYI.jpg)

please help me

Answer (score 1):

just uncomment the `extension=gd` in the `php.ini` file it removes that error and run the `composer update` cmd it will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

**Use this Command** `composer require maatwebsite/excel --ignore-platform-reqs`

Comment: Now i am getting this error after running this command

Comment: Problem 1
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.36, ..., 3.1.x-dev] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.18 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.18.0, ..., 1.23.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.0 requires illuminate/support ^5.5 -> found illuminate/support[v5.5.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Answer (score 0):

Why don´t you install required dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0-gd
```

and after that

```
composer require maatwebsite/excel
```